# 'magentoInfo' method missing from SOAP

Tags: soap

New to magento development so this might be a simple mistake, but why is this Schema missing the method magentoInfo? Do methods difference between enterprise and community?

http://www.cantonteaco.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl

EDIT:

The example client above 'Cantonteaco' is using version 1.5, which I'm guessing is the reason for the missing 'magentoInfo' method.

What other method can I use to get the version?

Comment: Turns out the example SOAP above is from a client of ours on a 1.5 version, is there functionality on this version that is missing? 

What is the best way of determining the version of a client if using 'magentoInfo' is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

I under stand your question now.

Version 1.5 does not have a call for retrieving the current version of your magento installation.

You will have to upgrade the API to a newer version or upgrade you magento version to 1.8 or above.

You can do the following.

Overwite app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\api.xml and app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\wsdl.xml v1.5 with v1.8 And add to v1.5 app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Api.php

Comment: What if the SOAP doesn't have either of those methods? Search the example SOAP and you won't find them.